# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in google translate api with node.js

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-translation-api

```
const projectId = 'natural-nebula-number';

const {
Translate
} = require('@google-cloud/translate').v2;

const translate = new Translate({
projectId,

});

async function quickStart() {

const text = 'Hello, world!';

const target = 'ru';
const [translation] = await translate.translate(text, target);
console.log(`Text: ${text}`);
console.log(`Translation: ${translation}`);

}

quickStart();
```

I wrote some code for using google translate api with node.js
i had install @google-cloud/translate. through npm.
and i did copy,paste code in this site [google api usage](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text#translate_translate_text-nodejs)

but i got some error on my command
here is the error message.

```
(node:440) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The request is missing a valid API key.
at new ApiError (/mnt/c/Users/U suk jang/Desktop/testinf/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:73:15)        
at Util.parseHttpRespBody (/mnt/c/Users/U suk jang/Desktop/testinf/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:208:38)
at Util.handleResp (/mnt/c/Users/U suk jang/Desktop/testinf/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:149:117)   
at /mnt/c/Users/U suk jang/Desktop/testinf/node_modules/@google-cloud/common/build/src/util.js:477:22
at onResponse (/mnt/c/Users/U suk jang/Desktop/testinf/node_modules/retry-request/index.js:228:7)
at /mnt/c/Users/U suk jang/Desktop/testinf/node_modules/teeny-request/build/src/index.js:226:13
```

i wrote actually full projectid (of couse real number).
but they say they cannot find my api key.
how should i give my api key to google
and where is the google-docs for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You copy-pasted the code in the link provided, but did you read the article and follow all prerequisite steps? It links to another article, [Cloud Translation: NodeJS Client](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/translate/latest#quickstart). There you will find that you need to pay special attention top step 4 (authentication) mentioned under the Quickstart paragraph. Without it, the used client library will not find your API key.